# How to get text in `::before` section with selenium and python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I would like to reach to text stored after `::before` in `variant__available-qty` class. In the example it is "14".

When I try with:

```
variants = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("variant__available-qty")
```

or

```
variants = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("variants__container-item")
```

It responds with an empty list, although there should be at least three elements.
I tried with executing some JS scripts (`driver.execute_script(...)`) but with no success.

```html
<div class="variants__container">
   <div class="variants__container-headers">
      <div class="variants__header--item">Rozmiar</div>
      <div class="variants__header--qty">Wybierz ilość</div>
   </div>
   <div class="variants__container-items">
      <div id="variant__70224" class="variants__container-item">
         <div class="variant__price">
            <div class="price">71.27&nbsp;zł</div>
         </div>
         <div class="variant__item">
            <div class="variant__attributes">35-37 </div>
            <div class="variant__sku">610306143389</div>
         </div>
         <div class="variant__qty">
            <form method="post" action="https://b2b.snapoutdoor.pl/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly9iMmIuc25hcG91dGRvb3IucGwvL3Jlc3QvVjEvZXh0ZW5kdmFyaWFudHN0b2NhcnQvODY1NDY_Xz0xNjAyMzE4NzI4Nzcz/product/86546/">
               <div class="qty">
                  <div class="qty-down">-</div>
                  <input type="number" name="qty" data-productid="70224" onfocus="this.value=''" value="0" min="0">
                  <div class="qty-up">+</div>
               </div>
               <input type="hidden" name="super_attribute[233]" value="2028"><input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="OPk3fByYxbAMTgnu"><button disabled="" class="add-to-cart action primary" type="submit">Do koszyka</button>
            </form>
         </div>
         <div class="variant__available-qty">12</div>
      </div>
      <div id="variant__70225" class="variants__container-item">
         <div class="variant__price">
            <div class="price">71.27&nbsp;zł</div>
         </div>
         <div class="variant__item">
            <div class="variant__attributes">38-40 </div>
            <div class="variant__sku">610306143396</div>
         </div>
         <div class="variant__qty">
            <form method="post" action="https://b2b.snapoutdoor.pl/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly9iMmIuc25hcG91dGRvb3IucGwvL3Jlc3QvVjEvZXh0ZW5kdmFyaWFudHN0b2NhcnQvODY1NDY_Xz0xNjAyMzE4NzI4Nzcz/product/86546/">
               <div class="qty">
                  <div class="qty-down">-</div>
                  <input type="number" name="qty" data-productid="70225" onfocus="this.value=''" value="0" min="0">
                  <div class="qty-up">+</div>
               </div>
               <input type="hidden" name="super_attribute[233]" value="2036"><input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="OPk3fByYxbAMTgnu"><button disabled="" class="add-to-cart action primary" type="submit">Do koszyka</button>
            </form>
         </div>
         <div class="variant__available-qty">14</div>
      </div>
      <div id="variant__70226" class="variants__container-item">
         <div class="variant__price">
            <div class="price">71.27&nbsp;zł</div>
         </div>
         <div class="variant__item">
            <div class="variant__attributes">41-43 </div>
            <div class="variant__sku">610306143402</div>
         </div>
         <div class="variant__qty">
            <form method="post" action="https://b2b.snapoutdoor.pl/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly9iMmIuc25hcG91dGRvb3IucGwvL3Jlc3QvVjEvZXh0ZW5kdmFyaWFudHN0b2NhcnQvODY1NDY_Xz0xNjAyMzE4NzI4Nzcz/product/86546/">
               <div class="qty">
                  <div class="qty-down">-</div>
                  <input type="number" name="qty" data-productid="70226" onfocus="this.value=''" value="0" min="0">
                  <div class="qty-up">+</div>
               </div>
               <input type="hidden" name="super_attribute[233]" value="2042"><input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="OPk3fByYxbAMTgnu"><button disabled="" class="add-to-cart action primary" type="submit">Do koszyka</button>
            </form>
         </div>
         <div class="variant__available-qty">6</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if u provide the url of the website.

Comment: @Sushil You would need to login to see this :(

Comment: Oh...:( Maybe u can do one thing. Copy paste the html code of the website in ur question. If not the entire html code, at least the relevant part of it.

Comment: assuming that there is only 1 element with class name variant__available-qty   
  
please  see https://seleniumbyexamples.github.io/findel

Comment: @slackingslacker as I wrote in the post, there are at least three elements and `find_elements_by_class_name` returns empty list

Comment: @Marta pls update the question with the html code. Only then we will be able to help u.

Comment: @Marta find_elements_by_class_name and find_element_by_class_name are different, first one return a list, second returns an element. As mentioned there are 3 different class names assuming that this is an item details page. Also try to add a delay time.sleep(20) before the code and see if there is a difference in the result.

Comment: @Marta Check whether my answer satisfies ur requirement

Comment: @slackingslacker I appreciate your answer, but the assumption that there is one `variant__available-qty` element is incorrect as there are at least three, this is why I used "elements"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can simply use `BeautifulSoup` for this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="variants__container">
   <div class="variants__container-headers">
      <div class="variants__header--item">Rozmiar</div>
      <div class="variants__header--qty">Wybierz ilość</div>
   </div>
   <div class="variants__container-items">
      <div id="variant__70224" class="variants__container-item">
         <div class="variant__price">
            <div class="price">71.27&nbsp;zł</div>
         </div>
         <div class="variant__item">
            <div class="variant__attributes">35-37 </div>
            <div class="variant__sku">610306143389</div>
         </div>
         <div class="variant__qty">
            <form method="post" action="https://b2b.snapoutdoor.pl/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly9iMmIuc25hcG91dGRvb3IucGwvL3Jlc3QvVjEvZXh0ZW5kdmFyaWFudHN0b2NhcnQvODY1NDY_Xz0xNjAyMzE4NzI4Nzcz/product/86546/">
               <div class="qty">
                  <div class="qty-down">-</div>
                  <input type="number" name="qty" data-productid="70224" onfocus="this.value=''" value="0" min="0">
                  <div class="qty-up">+</div>
               </div>
               <input type="hidden" name="super_attribute[233]" value="2028"><input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="OPk3fByYxbAMTgnu"><button disabled="" class="add-to-cart action primary" type="submit">Do koszyka</button>
            </form>
         </div>
         <div class="variant__available-qty">12</div>
      </div>
      <div id="variant__70225" class="variants__container-item">
         <div class="variant__price">
            <div class="price">71.27&nbsp;zł</div>
         </div>
         <div class="variant__item">
            <div class="variant__attributes">38-40 </div>
            <div class="variant__sku">610306143396</div>
         </div>
         <div class="variant__qty">
            <form method="post" action="https://b2b.snapoutdoor.pl/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly9iMmIuc25hcG91dGRvb3IucGwvL3Jlc3QvVjEvZXh0ZW5kdmFyaWFudHN0b2NhcnQvODY1NDY_Xz0xNjAyMzE4NzI4Nzcz/product/86546/">
               <div class="qty">
                  <div class="qty-down">-</div>
                  <input type="number" name="qty" data-productid="70225" onfocus="this.value=''" value="0" min="0">
                  <div class="qty-up">+</div>
               </div>
               <input type="hidden" name="super_attribute[233]" value="2036"><input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="OPk3fByYxbAMTgnu"><button disabled="" class="add-to-cart action primary" type="submit">Do koszyka</button>
            </form>
         </div>
         <div class="variant__available-qty">14</div>
      </div>
      <div id="variant__70226" class="variants__container-item">
         <div class="variant__price">
            <div class="price">71.27&nbsp;zł</div>
         </div>
         <div class="variant__item">
            <div class="variant__attributes">41-43 </div>
            <div class="variant__sku">610306143402</div>
         </div>
         <div class="variant__qty">
            <form method="post" action="https://b2b.snapoutdoor.pl/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly9iMmIuc25hcG91dGRvb3IucGwvL3Jlc3QvVjEvZXh0ZW5kdmFyaWFudHN0b2NhcnQvODY1NDY_Xz0xNjAyMzE4NzI4Nzcz/product/86546/">
               <div class="qty">
                  <div class="qty-down">-</div>
                  <input type="number" name="qty" data-productid="70226" onfocus="this.value=''" value="0" min="0">
                  <div class="qty-up">+</div>
               </div>
               <input type="hidden" name="super_attribute[233]" value="2042"><input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="OPk3fByYxbAMTgnu"><button disabled="" class="add-to-cart action primary" type="submit">Do koszyka</button>
            </form>
         </div>
         <div class="variant__available-qty">6</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
""" # The html code
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')

divs = soup.find_all('div',class_ = 'variant__available-qty')

for div in divs:
    print(div.text)
```

Output:

```
12
14
6
```

In my case, I have hardcoded the html. But u can extract the html code of the webpage using `driver.page_source`. Then u can convert that html to a `BeautifulSoup` object and perform these operations. If u still wanna use selenium, then try using the `xpaths` or `css selectors` instead of `class_names`. Hope that this helps!

Comment: I tried this but it cannot see the element. 
```
driver.get(product_link)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='variant__available-qty')
print("divs: ", divs)
for div in divs:
    print(div.text)
```
The result for divs is empty list

Comment: I see the formatting is wrong in comments, I added a gist with the example above here:
https://gist.github.com/martasobota/5998a7b8a3e41781dd5e18eb8fcd85e6

Comment: Doesn't this work? I tried the same with the html that u provided and it worked. What does it print for u?

Comment: Empty list. I guess there is some kind of protection, that it is visible manually in the browser, but selenium cannot see it, probably because of this `::before`

Comment: What does ```driver.page_source``` print?

Comment: @Marta try taking a screenshot of the page driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.png") to see if the page loaded the way you want it to be

Comment: @slackingslacker @Sushil true, after I took a screenshot, the page wasn't fully loaded and when I added `time.sleep(3)`, I can see proper results!!! Thank you!!!

Comment: glad to hear it worked. here are some examples of how to wait for different elements. https://seleniumbyexamples.github.io/wait